# How can I mathematically transform the default labels on legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a 2D surface plot made with ggplot which I am colouring to show the value of it's third dimension. This data is wide-ranging in the Z direction, so I have log-transformed it before doing the interpolation for plotting.

I like the default choices that the plotting algorithm has chosen for the breaks. However, the labels for those breaks are now the log values.

The current code for the colouring is:

```
scale_fill_viridis(breaks = waiver(), labels = waiver())
```

waiver() is a flag to the underlying algorithm to use default values. Ideally, I'd like to do something like

```
scale_fill_viridis(breaks = waiver(), labels = sprintf("%.1f", 10^waiver()))
```

but that breaks with a `Error in 10^my_breaks : non-numeric argument to binary operator` error

How can I mathematically transform the default values for the labels into the values they would be prior to the log transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
your_function <- function(x){sprintf("%.1f", 10^as.numeric(x))}

labels = scales::trans_format("identity", your_function)
```

`your_function` will take the inverse of `log10`, effectively undoing the log transform.  `scales::trans_format` will reformat the given label by applying whatever function it passed to it, in this case `your_function`.

You can of course define the reformatting function inside `trans_format` but in order to make things as clear as possible I've done it in two steps.